# Не изменяется размер колонки TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms

Что тут не так ?

Почему не изменяется ширина колонки ?

```
    private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int n = this.Size.Width; // Получаю ширину окна
        label10.Text = "Ширина окна: " + n.ToString();

        float x = this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles[1].Width; // Получаю ширину колонки
        label11.Text = "Ширина 1-ой колонки: " + x.ToString();

        float y = n - this.MinimumSize.Width;
        label12.Text = "Разница: " + y.ToString();

        this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles[1].Width = y;

        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Refresh();
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы хотите что бы обе колонки масштабировались при растяжении формы ? Почему не перейти на WPF ?

Comment: @Сергей, 2-я колонка и так масштабируется за счёт того, что её ширина 100%. А мне нужно увеличивать программно только ширину 1-ой колонки на столько же пикселей, на сколько я увеличиваю форму.

До WPF пока не дошёл, так как мало знаний ещё тут, но что то уже получается. А там придётся сталкиваться ещё с чем то новым, а пока не до этого.

Comment: У вас написано `this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles[1].Width = y` но вы хотите увеличивать размер только первого столбца. Не лучше ли тогда вместо 1 поставить 0 ?

Comment: @Сергей, блин, вот я и попался xD - Думал там начинается с 1, а не с 0
Точнее даже не думал, а просто в подсознании сидело. Как всегда, всё просто. Спасибо вам что не прошли мимо !

Comment: Пожалуйста! Надеюсь вам помог мой ответ. Сам в вашем примере не сразу сообразил в чем ошибка, так что вы не первый )

Comment: + вопросу за наглядность!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первый элемент в массивах в с# имеет индекс 0 а не 1. Раз нужно менять ширину первого столбика то и обращаться следует к элементу под индексом 0.

Поменяйте :

```
this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles[1].Width = y;
```

на :

```
this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles[0].Width = y;
```

Советую все же для приложений со сложным интерфейсом использовать WPF.